# Why is COM ignoring my DllSurrogate entry?

Tags: com

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706429/how-exactly-do-i-config-dcom-to-load-my-dll-into-a-separate-process), but I've followed the steps listed there and I'm still stumped.

I've got a class, registered as follows (this is an RGS file):

```
HKCR
{
    NoRemove CLSID
    {
        ForceRemove {5CB1D770-BF72-4F3D-B4DA-85E0542126F4} = s 'ExamplePlugin Class'
        {
            val AppID = s '%APPID%'
            InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
            {
                val ThreadingModel = s 'Free'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've got an AppID, registered as follows:

```
HKCR
{
    NoRemove AppID
    {
        '%APPID%' = s 'ExamplePlugin'
        {
            val DllSurrogate = s ''
        }
        'ExamplePlugin.DLL'
        {
            val AppID = s '%APPID%'
        }
    }
}
```

I'm passing `CLSCTX_ALL` to `CComPtr<IPlugin>::CoCreateInstance`.

In short, as far as I can tell, I've followed [the checklist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686606.aspx):

1. I have an AppID value specified under my CLSID. I have a corresponding AppID key.
2. I've included `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` in the activation call. My CLSID key does not have any LocalServer keys.
3. My CLSID key contains an InprocServer32 key.
4. I assume that when the checklist says "the proxy/stub DLL specified in InprocServer32 exists", it means "the implementing DLL". It does exist. My proxy/stub DLL is correctly registered elsewhere.
5. I have a DllSurrogate value under my AppID key.

If I look at my class in OLE/COM object viewer, it appears to be correct (the Implementation tab has "Use Surrogate Process" checked).

It's still not working: my DLL is loading into the same process as my host EXE.

A clue: If I run Process Monitor, I can't see it looking for the `CLSID\{...}\AppID` value. If I pass `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` to CoCreateInstance, I get "class not registered" returned.

I'm on Windows 2008 x64, but I've tried with my code compiled for both x86 and x64 with the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see your application in DCOM console?

Comment: Also are you absolutely positively sure that when you roll in those .rgs files you pass exactly the right AppId each time as substitution string? Does it look right in the registry after that?

Comment: Update: when I explicitly pass CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, I get a surrogate-hosted instance. I'm not sure why I couldn't get it working before.

Comment: That's exactly the same way it worked for me. I'll undelete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the documentation is misleading. It's not enough merely to set CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER. You also have to **remove the CLSCTX_INPROC values** from the call to CoCreateInstance. If you don't, COM will always use the in-proc stuff, and will never query for DllSurrogate.

Answer (score 3):

You have to spefify `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` to CoCreateInstance() to enforce out-proc activation. That's peculiarity of DCOM - if your component is registered as an in-proc COM server and you specify a CLSCTX_ mask including any value for in-proc activation the component is activated in-proc - DCOM is not used.

Note that COM+ provides almost the same functionality but if you create a "server application" and add your component there and then specify CLSCTX_ALL the component will be instantiated in COM+ surrogate - out-proc activation will be selected automatically.

Comment: It's not that you have to specify CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, it's that you have to explicitly *not* specify any inproc flags.

Comment: ...and how do I create a COM+ server application? More to the point: how do I do this from my installer?

Comment: Yeap, I see. Actualy I meant exactly that.

Comment: ...moreover, having played with DCOMCNFG, it appears that COM+ "applications" need specific activation credentials. I'd like to opt for "whoever created it".

Comment: @sharptooth: They're bitflags. It's not enough to say "specify this flag". You have to say "specify _only_ this flag". The COM documentation makes the same mistake.

Comment: Install Shield surely does that but I don't know the details. As far as I know it works like this: you create a COM+ application, then import it into Install Shield package, then it can deploy the COM+ application on any machine. Server applications can be activated under the "Interactive user" identity - that's the currently logged-in user.

Comment: Yeah: I don't want to use "Interactive user". My COM client runs as a service under whatever account's configured for that service. That's the account I'd like the COM class instantiated under. In other words "whoever".