# Can I force my COM object to use DllSurrogate?

Tags: com

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880288/why-is-com-ignoring-my-dllsurrogate-entry) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706429/how-exactly-do-i-config-dcom-to-load-my-dll-into-a-separate-process).

It turns out that to load a COM class into a surrogate process, you **must not** specify any of the `CLSCTX_INPROC` flags when calling CoCreateInstance.

So: how do I allow my host to use `CLSCTX_ALL`, but allow the individual COM classes to opt in to using DLLHOST?

The reason I ask is that I locate my COM classes by using component categories, and I pass `CLSCTX_ALL` when creating them. I'd like most of them to be in-proc, but for some of them to be able to be out-of-proc.